# Sending concurrent http requests per sec through Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

preparing test plan to send multiple http request. However, jmeter waits to send another batch of request till it gets response from first batch.

I want to send 10 concurrent requests per sec. If i run 1 mins, i should have 600 requests in the then. However, since jmeter waits to send another 10 concurrent requests till it gets response from previous 10 requests, I can't send 10 concurrent requests.

any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to go for [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) which tries to maintain the defined concurrency level by kicking off new threads if current amount is not enough to conduct the required throughput. So basically you need to install Concurrency Thread Group via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) and migrate your Sampler(s) there.

More information: [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter Part 4 - Stepping Thread Group and Concurrency Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread)